# printing scalar as int32 in Matlab

Tags: matlab, type-conversion, integer, signed

I'm trying to print scalar as it would look like if it was int32. That is, if I have `2532063508`, if I write it in 4 bytes and read as int32, I would read `-1762903788`.

using `int32` function in Matlab didn't work, because the way it works is, values outside the range `[-2^31,2^31-1]` map to the nearest endpoint.

So I tried to use `typecast`:

```
typecast(uint32(2532063508), 'int32')
```

works perfectly, but if I write e.g. -1 there, uint32() returns 0 so it fails.

P.S. I want it to work for signed integers as input as well, that is, for -1 it should return -1

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do calculations in `int64` then convert to `uint32`:

```
f = @(x)typecast(uint32(mod(int64(x),int64(2)^32)),'int32');
```

Or

```
function y = f(x)
    y = typecast(uint32(mod(int64(x),int64(2)^32)),'int32');
end
```

So `f([-1, 2532063508])` returns `[-1, -1762903788]`.

Comment: not sure if I got it, can you please write it as y=f(x) form where I input `x=[-1, 2532063508] and it would return `[-1, -1762903788]` ?